# Database - Migration Repository - Git

Tags: git, oracle11g, package, gitlab, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect a live database to GitLab through Oracle SQL Developer.
I have a Git connection working in "Team", and a working connection to a database. How can I connect the two of them? I guess it has something to do with the "Migration Repository" option, but it seems it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.